# Open panelaccordion item programmatically in an ADF popup

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

In an Oracle ADF web app I have a popup that users access in order to fill out a detail form.  The information entry is broken up using a panelaccordion with only two detail items.  Panelaccordions I have noticed remember which item was showing when they were last viewed, so if a user cancels the popup with the second detail section open that section will be open when they access the popup a second time.

I want to force the panelaccordion to be showing the first detail section each time the popup is accessed (currently this occurs with a button click).  I haven't found any info on pro grammatically setting which section of the accordion is showing, or to simply reset it to it's beginning state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the disclosed property of the showDetailItem to true in a backing bean - similar to how you would do it with tabs:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deciding_which_tab_to_show